# How can I cancel a JS function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to create a functioning filter button. The script below allows me to filter the list depending on what filter option is selected.

I would like to include a clear button, something that clears the filter applied. Preferably if it cancels the corresponding function.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

```js
$('#filterLevel').change(function(){
  var level = $(this).val();
  $("#listTeachers").find("li").hide()
      $.each($("#listTeachers").find("li"),function(){
          if($(this).data('filtertext')==level)
              $(this).show();

      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Filter Panel - County Job Filter -->
<div data-role="panel" id="schoolfilterPanel" data-display="overlay" data-position="left">
    <form id="filterJobs">
    <p class="filterHeader">FILTER</p>
    <h1 class="filterCountyHeader">Teaching Level:</h1>
        <select id="filterLevel" onchange='filterLevel()'><option disabled selected>Select level...</option><option value="Primary">Primary School</option><option value="Secondary">Secondary School</option></select><br>
    </form>
    <button id="clearButton">CLEAR</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add a blank option to the filter selection.  If blank is selected, don't apply a filter.  Else, apply a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$("#clearButton").click(function(){
 $("#listTeachers").find("li").show();
});
```

Comment: if `.find("li")` becomes an expensive operation where an end user abuses the clear button, you can add a conditional around this with something like `$(this).hasClass("applied")`, and remove the "applied" class when a filter is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean `cancelFilter` variable (maybe on the global scope) that your anonymous function can look up each time it is executed.

```
<script>

var cancelFilter = false;

$('#filterLevel').change(function(){

    cancelFilter = false;

    var level = $(this).val();

    $("#listTeachers").find("li").hide();

    $.each($("#listTeachers").find("li"),function(){

        if(cancelFilter)
        {

            // do whatever you need to reset the list...


            // returning false will break the $.each() loop
            return false;
        }

        if($(this).data('filtertext')==level)
        {
            $(this).show();
        }

    });

});

</script>
```

Then have your "cancel" button change `cancelFilter` to `true`